# Get multiple fields out of JSON [Python]

Tags: python, json, list

I have some JSON files with structure as described below:

```
{
    "paragraphs": [
        "Fake anti-virus software that infect PCs with malicious code are a growing threat, according to a study by Google.", 
        "Its analysis of 240m web pages over 13 months showed that fake anti-virus programs accounted for 15% of all malicious software.", 
        "Scammers trick people into downloading programs by convincing them that their PC is infected with a virus.", 
    ], 
    "description": "Google has found ...", 
    "title": "Google warning on fake anti-virus software"
},
```

I need to iterate and grab all title fields from multiple instances like this one (which are in the same JSON file) and store them in a new list. Can somebody help on how I could do that in Python? It will be great if you can how I can do that on the paragraph field as well as I have multiple entries there instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module, to parse your json file into the structure of nested dicts and lists.
2. Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract your descriptions, like

   ```
   titles = [x['title'] for x in parsed_json]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did sth like :

```
with open("out.json") as j:
    json_data = j.read()
    data = json.loads(json_data)

for x in range(0,len(data)):
    print data[x]['title']
```

And it worked. There only thing now is how to get every paragraph since there are multiple instances for each paragraph section as displayed above.